# Application icon on authorization page isn't loading

Tags: bug, oauth2, icons

I can't seem to get the application icon for Stack Applet to display on the authorization page. (I'm using the implicit flow.) The URL that I open the browser to is:

> https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=120&scope=read_inbox&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success

This is what my browser displays:

---

[image]

---

Notice that the application icon isn't loading correctly. A bit of digging reveals that the page is using the following (non-existent) URL for the image:

> https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/apps-icons/8/120.png

The correct URL of the image is:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RMgO.png

Comment: https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/apps-icons/8/120.png displays perfectly fine for me.  Maybe it's your browser, your machine, or your network?  (I did purge my cache too.)

Comment: @Brock: weird. I tried both Firefox and Chromium - neither worked. It works in Chrome for Android though. I'll try it again on the desktop later.

Comment: Could be your machine's DNS (cache), or your local router.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue